# setImageResource crashes application when invoked

Tags: java, android

I try to set `IV_status.setImageResource(R.drawable.red)`

but it does not seems like its working and whenever the above code is invoked,the whole app

will crash.I also tried `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red)` but the same issue is

happening. it crashes before it can go to the activity screen.

```
public class PhotosActivity extends ListActivity {
// Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;
    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://10.0.8.41/pos/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "tables";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "tableID";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "tableName";
    private static final String TAG_AREA = "area";
    private static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";
    static ImageView IV_status;
    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photos_layout);
    IV_status = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.status);

    IV_status.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
    // Hashmap for ListView
            productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            // Loading products in Background Thread
            new LoadAllProducts().execute();

            // Get listview
            ListView lv = getListView();

            // on seleting single product
            // launching Edit Product Screen



        }

        // Response from Edit Product Activity
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            // if result code 100
            if (resultCode == 100) {
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }

        /**
         * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
         * */
        class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PhotosActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            /**
             * getting All products from url
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

                // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

                try {
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {

                        products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);


                        for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                            String area = c.getString(TAG_AREA);
                            String status = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);
                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                            map.put(TAG_AREA,area);
                            map.put(TAG_STATUS, status);
                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            if(area.equals("A")){

                                    productsList.add(map);


                            }



                    } else {
                        // no products found
                        // Launch Add New product Activity
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PhotosActivity.class);// Closing all previous activities
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                pDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        /**
                         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                         * */

                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                PhotosActivity.this, productsList,R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,TAG_NAME},
                                new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                        // updating listview
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });

            }

        }
    }
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Product id (pid) - will be HIDDEN - used to pass to other activity -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Log with stack trace:

```
07-26 05:50:49.379: D/dalvikvm(3118): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 41K, 7% free 2614K/2804K, paused 33ms, total 37ms
07-26 05:50:49.464: D/AndroidRuntime(3118): Shutting down VM
07-26 05:50:49.464: W/dalvikvm(3118): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tabhost/com.example.tabhost.AndroidTabLayoutActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tabhost/com.example.tabhost.PhotosActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tabhost/com.example.tabhost.PhotosActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2023)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at com.example.tabhost.AndroidTabLayoutActivity.onCreate(AndroidTabLayoutActivity.java:40)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     ... 11 more
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at com.example.tabhost.PhotosActivity.onCreate(PhotosActivity.java:54)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-26 05:50:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3118):     ... 21 more
07-26 05:50:49.722: D/dalvikvm(3118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 174K, 11% free 2860K/3180K, paused 128ms+41ms, total 246ms
```

Listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please post the stack trace of the error, you can get it from logcat

Comment: The extract from the log with the stacktrace would be usefull.

Comment: IV_status = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.status);please check the id of the Imageview that are same in xml layout

Comment: Stack Trace needed from Logcat.....!!!

Comment: where is error pointing to

Comment: Its getting null pointer exception in your Oncreate of PhotoActivity. which means you are using Null variable somewhere. debug and try to catch that.

Comment: Where the line #54 of PhotosActivity.java is actually pointing to?

Comment: Line #54 -   IV_status.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red));

Comment: I tested your code and it worked, is there something wrong with your resource 'red'?

Comment: i used android:src="@drawable/red" it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify the Line you have like this

```
IV_status.setImageResource(R.drawable.red)
```

to this

```
IV_status.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red));
```

now run your code it will work

the reson of app being crashed is that it did not get resource so you need to give it track of resource as mentioned above

Comment: The method setImageResource(int) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (Drawable)
i got this error

Comment: As I see from API refference, setImageResource(int) accepts resource id from xml layout, not the Drawable object.

Comment: you can use also use the following method despite using above
IV_status.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red));

Comment: still crashing.. after adding IV_status.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red));

Comment: the stack trace is posted above on part 2

Comment: @user2408603 the one vivible mistake is you don't have a listview with id `android:id="@android:id/list"` in your xml

Comment: there is 
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

Comment: yes your listview has now Reference and direct you are assigning it to method so due to null refrence app is getting crashed

Comment: @user2408603 where is your listview in xml? i don't see it and which line is line 54?

Comment: Line #54 - IV_status.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red));

Comment: listview is in another activity

Comment: @user2408603 that can't be null. i just tried it out. may be clean an build and post new logcat. you cannot have listview in anoter activity. it must be in same xml `photos_layout`.